# invoke a rest service from command prompt

Tags: wcf, rest, command-line

I need to invoke a wcf rest service from command prompt. For eg, when i type

```
C:\Users\Admin>GET http://localhost:63088/RestCatalogService.svc/
```

it should return whatever the GET would return in a browser in string format.Any idea how to start with or links to any related resources will be greatly helpful.

Comment: The simplest way might be to install cygwin and curl.

Comment: Install libwww-perl.  It includes a program called "GET".

Answer (score 5):

Install your favorite HTTP tool ([cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) into your PATH, then use it.

Do note that that would look something more like :

```
C:\Users\Admin>curl http://localhost:63088/RestCatalogService.svc/
```

or

```
C:\Users\Admin>wget -O - http://localhost:63088/RestCatalogService.svc/
```

Comment: I am building a catalog service and i need to post,put and delete along with get on the products. I havent used these tools earlier. would they work for the other methods too?

Comment: If i want to create my own application(something like creating a GET bat file in system32 and calling the web service from the bat(I may be totally wrong)) then how do i proceed.?

Comment: cURL is without any doubt the most extensive HTTP client that's out there. It supports PUT, POST, and literally every other method that's out there, even [`BREW`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2324.txt).